# Sqrt only one column in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following 2D array, and want to take a square root of only column A.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]])
a

matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6],
        [7, 8]])
```

This is giving me sqrt of two columns. How can I only take a square root of column A?

```
b = np.sqrt(a[:, [0, 1]])
b


matrix([[1.        , 1.41421356],
        [1.73205081, 2.        ],
        [2.23606798, 2.44948974],
        [2.64575131, 2.82842712]])
```

Comment: What's column A?

Comment: Column A is position 0 of given matrix. I only want to sqrt it and display the matrix.

Comment: Beware [NumPy's `matrix` is deprecated](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html), please use a plain `ndarray` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `out` to do in place operation

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], dtype=np.float64)
np.sqrt(a, where=[True, False],out=a)
```

Output:

```
[[1.         2.        ]
 [1.73205081 4.        ]
 [2.23606798 6.        ]
 [2.64575131 8.        ]]
```

---

##### [Try it online](https://onecompiler.com/python/3y4bbnkep)

Comment: This seems to me like the best answer to the query. I believe it could be improved by emphasizing that the numpy sqrt (and, i assume, most others) support a "where" option to apply it to part of the given array.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'm just going to have to put my answer here:

You can do it in-place with the following:

```
a = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], dtype=np.float)
a[:, 0] = np.sqrt(a[:, 0])
```

Do note that because your initial types were `int`, that you must specify the `dtype=np.float` if not it will all get cast to ints.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only first column, you must this

```
b = np.sqrt(a[:, [0]])
```

if you want all columns but first columns sqrt, you try this

```
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
df.loc[:,0]=df.loc[:,0].apply(np.sqrt)
```